# Incorrect # of Free Hugepages in `numastat`

Tags: linux, centos7, kernel, numa

```
$ numastat -vm

Per-node system memory usage (in MBs):
                          Node 0           Total
                 --------------- ---------------
MemTotal                32464.24        32464.24
MemFree                 30993.97        30993.97
MemUsed                  1470.27         1470.27
Active                     47.68           47.68
Inactive                  158.69          158.69
Active(anon)               10.48           10.48
Inactive(anon)              8.99            8.99
Active(file)               37.21           37.21
Inactive(file)            149.70          149.70
Unevictable                 0.00            0.00
Mlocked                     0.00            0.00
Dirty                       0.00            0.00
Writeback                   0.00            0.00
FilePages                 196.26          196.26
Mapped                     13.79           13.79
AnonPages                   9.82            9.82
Shmem                       9.36            9.36
KernelStack                 3.86            3.86
PageTables                  1.91            1.91
NFS_Unstable                0.00            0.00
Bounce                      0.00            0.00
WritebackTmp                0.00            0.00
Slab                       41.54           41.54
SReclaimable               17.00           17.00
SUnreclaim                 24.54           24.54
AnonHugePages               0.00            0.00
HugePages_Total           256.00          256.00
HugePages_Free            254.00          254.00
HugePages_Surp              0.00            0.00
$ ll /mnt/huge2m/
total 2048
-rw-rw-rw- 1 as as 2097152 Dec 18 20:32 request.0
-rw-rw-rw- 1 as as 2097152 Dec 18 20:32 response.0
```

For some reason, even tho two 2MB hugepages (request.0 and response.0 exists), only 1 is counted?  As `numastat` states there is 256MB total of hugepages and 254MB are free.

Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HugePages_Total` and `HugePages_Free` units are pages, in this case 2MB pages. See [Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt). (Two significant digits are slightly misleading, page counts are integers.)

Note that -m is the "meminfo-like" option, it does not mean MB.

Comment: It is the first line of `numastat  -vm`'s output misleading me -- `Per-node system memory usage (in *MBs*)`.  Thanks.