# Incorrect # of Hugepages in `numstat`

Tags: linux, centos7, kernel, numa

I asked a similar [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/996028/incorrect-of-free-hugepages-in-numastat) years ago.

Now, my machine has four 1G hugepages and 256 2MB hugepages:

```
# cat /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages
4
# cat /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
256
```

But then `numstat -vm` shows:

```
Per-node system memory usage (in MBs):
                          Node 0           Total
                 --------------- ---------------
MemTotal                65205.89        65205.89
MemFree                 58656.55        58656.55
MemUsed                  6549.34         6549.34
Active                    158.62          158.62
Inactive                   89.90           89.90
Active(anon)               15.32           15.32
Inactive(anon)              9.04            9.04
Active(file)              143.30          143.30
Inactive(file)             80.86           80.86
Unevictable                10.69           10.69
Mlocked                    10.69           10.69
Dirty                       0.02            0.02
Writeback                   0.00            0.00
FilePages                 235.87          235.87
Mapped                     16.08           16.08
AnonPages                  23.42           23.42
Shmem                       9.43            9.43
KernelStack                 5.38            5.38
PageTables                  2.84            2.84
NFS_Unstable                0.00            0.00
Bounce                      0.00            0.00
WritebackTmp                0.00            0.00
Slab                       50.60           50.60
SReclaimable               23.14           23.14
SUnreclaim                 27.46           27.46
AnonHugePages               0.00            0.00
HugePages_Total          4096.00         4096.00
HugePages_Free           4096.00         4096.00
HugePages_Surp              0.00            0.00
```

Based on the answer for my previous post, 4096 should be an "unit".  Now, I am confused.  Unit of what here?

It seems to me the "unit" is "MB" and `numastat` doesn't include those 2MB hugepages?

And why 2MB hugepages aren't reported here?

Answer (score 2):

Huge pages on Linux isn't the easiest to understand. Especially when some tools show things others do not, and everyone's doing their own unit conversions.

[System wide `/proc/meminfo`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.12/admin-guide/mm/hugetlbpage.html) will show the sum of all sizes of large pages as `Hugetlb`

> ### Hugetlb
>
> is the total amount of memory (in kB), consumed by huge pages of all
> sizes. If huge pages of different sizes are in use, this number will
> exceed HugePages_Total * Hugepagesize. To get more detailed
> information, please, refer to /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages

[numastat -m](https://github.com/jmesmon/numactl/blob/master/numastat.c#L100) will output "meminfo-like" based on per NUMA node stats in `/sys/devices/system/node/node?/meminfo`  but it also converts units to MB. I don't know why this apparently lacks a sum of all sizes. Maybe the kernel punted on this and lets user tools do what they want with per node data? Presumably the output you got is only the 4x 1GB pages.

[hugeadm](https://github.com/libhugetlbfs/libhugetlbfs/blob/2.21/hugeadm.c) (from libhugetlbfs) bases its recommended shmmax by summing each of the page sizes in `/sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/`.  `hugeadm --explain` is also useful to check default and size of each pool.

---

Using only one huge page size might be simpler to operate. Less than 5 GB of 2 MB pages is relatively small, these could all be 2 MB. 1 GB page size works, but could be an inefficient use of space for small allocations.

Comment: yeah, for some reason, `munstat -m`'s `HugePages_Total` and `HugePages_Free` don't include 2MB hugepages.  Mainly, I would like to find out the # of hugepages in different sizes when I have to troubleshoot issues on the machine.  However, when having two different sizes of hugepages, `numastat` doesn't correctly state the # of free hugepages.  I tried `hugeadm --explain` and it does clearly state the # of hugepages allocated for each size.  Tho, it doesn't tell how many free hugepages for each.  Any idea where I can dig out # of free hugepages for each size?  Thanks!

Comment: I do not know offhand which tool counts `/sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-*/free_hugepages`  correctly for every size.

Comment: I just tried to allocate two 1G pages and one 2M page and then `cat /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-*/free_hugepages`, it showed `4` and `256`, which aren't correct.